# GCP Cloud Composer : Audit the status of the Dags from Apache Airflow into BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to audit all the information about the DAGs execution status into a table BigQuery ,
I want to do this through a python code in Dags , as already have written code  is loading the data into the BigQuery table (as given below). Need help to append the  audit logic in the existing code.

with models.DAG(
'C360_GBL_CCN2DPN_CLASSIC',
default_args=default_args,
#schedule_interval='0 9 * * * ') as dag:
schedule_interval=None) as dag:
start = dummy_operator.DummyOperator(
task_id='start',
trigger_rule='all_success'
)
read_json_file(config_file_path)
end = dummy_operator.DummyOperator(
task_id='end',
trigger_rule='all_success'
)

```
a=[]
if (len(configurations) > 1):

    for k in range(0,len(configurations)):
        config=configurations[k]
        project_id = config['Project_Id']
        staging_dataset = config['Dataset']        
        table_name = config['Table-Name']
        write_disposition =config['write_disposition']
        sql = config['Sql']
        create_disposition = config['create_disposition']
        a.append(BigQueryOperator(
                task_id=table_name+'_ccn_2_dpn_bq',
                sql=sql,
                write_disposition=write_disposition,
                create_disposition=create_disposition,
                use_legacy_sql=False
            ))  
        if k != 0 :
            a[k-1].set_downstream(a[k])
        else:
            a[k].set_upstream(start)
    a[len(configurations)-1].set_downstream(end)
        
else:
    config = configurations[0]
    project_id = config['Project_Id']
    staging_dataset = config['Dataset']        
    table_name = config['Table-Name']
    write_disposition = config['write_disposition']
    sql = config['Sql']
    create_disposition = config['create_disposition']
    Task1 = BigQueryOperator(
            task_id=table_name+'_ccn_2_dpn_bq',
            sql=sql,
            write_disposition=write_disposition,
            create_disposition=create_disposition,
            use_legacy_sql=False
        )  

    Task1.set_upstream(start)
    Task1.set_downstream(end)
```

Comment: from question it's not clear what are you trying to do what's the error your are getting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As previously mentioned, yor error is not clear, could you please provide what error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow writes all the audit log to the table `log` in its metadata database, you can check if the information are enough for your needs, and if it's the case, you can export them to `BigQuery` using a stream app (if you need them ASAP after they are created) or by an airflow dag in two steps using the official operators:

1. a task form `PostgresToGCSOperator` to export the data to GCS
2. then a second task from `GCSToBigQueryOperator` to import the exported files into your BigQuery table,

or in one step using a new operator (you need to develop it).